# Custom Facebook share button with custom title,url,image in wordpress

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I know there may be many such question in stack-overflow . but i am not getting solution what i want

i am using wordpress. In my all post page there is share button ( **via addthis plugin** ) but what happening is when i click to share on Facebook ( **via addthis plugin** )  its taking all thing perfect i means url,title but images is taken something else.

[demo url](http://www.thefansworld.com/happy-new-year-trailer/).

So i tried to made custom share button which is below the addthis plugin :

Thats : **Custom Share on Facebook page!**  but when i click on it nothing happens also my title and link is shown on website : below is code of my custom Facebook share :

```
  <?php
    $title = the_title();
    $url= the_permalink();
    $summary=urlencode('Custom message that summarizes what your tab is about,  or just a simple message to tell people to check out your tab.');
    $image= wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ),  'single-post-thumbnail' );
  ?>
    <a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo $image[0];?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" target="_parent" href="javascript: void(0)">
        Custom Share on Facebook page!
    </a>
```

I have also putted OpenGrap tag in my wordpress header.php between head line

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="" />  
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" /> 
<meta property="og:video" content="" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="560" />  
<meta property="og:video:height" content="340" />  
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

please let me know what going wrong and where. i need all my post from my website  should be share on Facebook and twitter with it title,images( thats **resp post** image not any other image from website which is happening now ) and its  description )

[Working reference link](http://www.storypick.com/every-delhi-girl-response/)

**UPDATE NOW :**

After long here there i found https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefansworld.com%2Fhappy-new-year-trailer%2F

here when i putted my link there is showing my features images but under :

`When shared, this is what will be included` you will see something else (images )

Comment: You are using `$post->ID`, so how are you getting the `$post` object?

Comment: hey henrywright first of all thanks for reply , i was waiting from long .. i need solution on this badly ... i have just place that code above and i think wordpress is taking it by default ..as if u see source code of resp. pages you can see " <meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE LINK COME HERE ( WHICH IS FEATURE IMAGE OF RESP. POST" /> "

Comment: are you still there with me ?

Comment: pls chk update question now

Comment: i think i have solved it .. but still any master can check and please let me know :)

Comment: Can you post an update on how you solved it?

Comment: yes sure will do it. first let me check all is working fine or not :)... if all working fine will update the working code here

Comment: please check answer , but still some post have prb and it also have solution:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After here and there for long i find the solution for above :

Replaced above meta tag with below

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );  ?>

<?php if($image[0] != "" ){ ?>

<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"  >

<?php } else { ?>

<meta property="og:image" content="logo.png"  >

<?php } ?>


<meta property="og:image:width" content="3523" >

<meta property="og:image:height" content="2372" >

<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"  >

<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo the_title(); ?>"  > 

<meta property="og:site_name" content="Thefansworld" />

<meta property="og:description" content="" >  

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="3668661019" >

<meta property="fb:admins" content="" >

 <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

*But still some of the POST give me wrong images and after some research i found :*

When pulling a webpage from an URL, Facebook caches it's content for later. It means, that if Facebook once pulls data from your site, and than your site changes (for example your og:image tags change), Facebook will not change the image, because it already has everything cached on its side.

Try visiting [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) page and review what Facebook "sees". Using this tool forces Facebook to refresh data from the given URL. This is the best way to debug it.

When you make sure Facebook "sees" proper og:image tags, then make sure the images in the og:image are of proper minimum width/height (it's all explained in the fb debugger).

Facebook will not use an image from og:image if it does not meet FB's criteria. I strongly recommend this tool whenever there are any issues with content from your site on FB.

Hope this will help some one.And if i am wrong some where please let me know :)